# Unit test hyperledger fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am new to hyper-ledger fabric, after writing chaincode I don’t like to deploy and test every time. Is there any way to test the chaincode logic without deploying..

Answer (score 6):

To test the chaincode, in the directory containing the chaincode simply do

```
go test
```

See [chaincode_example02_test.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02/chaincode_example02_test.go) for an example of how to write tests for chaincode.

Comment: Great, Thanks mate.. I will have a look on that.

Comment: Link is invalid